# D3.js sorting the rows of a heatmap by column values - approaches?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to animate a heatmap grid that describes the ranks of an arbitrary parameter in different countries (rows) across years (columns). The initial map is here:

http://bl.ocks.org/phattwizat/5471768

I'd like to reorganize the rows by the ascending values of the 6th column in a transition, however I'm struggling to identify how to specify the selection and the subsequent sort that is necessary.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to best implement the sort. Can someone advise? Debating whether I should reformat the data, perhaps into an array of objects - 1 for each row with column data as object attributes if it simplifies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With D3, it is generally best to work with an [array of objects](http://www.jeromecukier.net/blog/2012/05/28/manipulating-data-like-a-boss-with-d3/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+JeromeCukier+%28Jerome+Cukier%29&utm_content=Google+Reader). You're close to a good solution, but maintaining the hierarchy of rows and columns is creating a headache for you.

To makes things simpler, create an array with an object representing each square you want to graph from your dataset object:

```
data = []; 
dataset.forEach(function(d){
    for (year = 2003; year < 2010; year++){
        data.push({"year": year, "Country": d["Country Name"], "value": d[year]});
    }
});
```

Now that the data is in the appropriate format, displaying the grid only takes a few lines of code:

```
var cells = grid.selectAll("rect")
            .data(data)
        .enter().append("svg:rect")
        .attr("class", function(d){ return color(d.value); })
        .attr("x", function(d) { return (d.year - 2003)*cellSize; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return (countryOrder.indexOf(d.Country))*cellSize; })
        .attr("width", cellSize - cellBorder)
        .attr("height", cellSize - cellBorder)
```

Changing the sort order is as easy as changing the countryOrder array and fancy transitions are just a [tutorial](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions) away!

```
var countryOrder = ["USA", "France", "Italy", "Canada", "Germany", "Ireland"];
```

http://bl.ocks.org/1wheel/5475820

Comment: I've been able to modify this to my needs and found it quite helpful.  I'm having a little difficulty utilizing this code to limit the selection, say to the top 2 or 3 rows by year, but still working on that issue.